# How can I tell whether an object is a prefab asset or an instance of that prefab?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I determine whether a game object is a prefab asset or is an instance of a prefab within my scene?

I tried making a custom editor and doing

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
   if (EditorUtility.IsPersistent(this.target))
   {
      Debug.Log("is persisent");
   }
   else
   {
      Debug.Log("is not persistent");
   }
}
```

But whether I select the prefab asset in the Project view or I select the prefab instance in my scene, both scenarios print "is not persistent"

The reason I'm doing this is that I want to have a MonoBehaviour with a `Guid` field, and the MonoBehaviour should generate a unique GUID for itself if it's part of a game object within a scene, but it should leave its `Guid` field blank if its part of a prefab asset (so that each instance of the same prefab gets a unique GUID).

Comment: sounds more like you need a factory or prefab manager, but technically they are all prefab instances in your scene, there only assets in there folder.

Comment: PrinceOfRavens is right, scenes don't contain assets (including prefabs). Unity instead creates prototypes that it clones when you call Instantiate. But maybe there is a way to distinguish those prototypes.

Comment: You maybe able to tell with https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.PrefabOverride.html - it sounds a bit like a long shot

Comment: maybe using [PrefabUtility.IsPartOfPrefabInstance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.IsPartOfPrefabInstance.html)?

Comment: Be aware that some of the functions being used here are Editor methods that won't work when you build your game. I can't tell if you already know that or not.

Comment: @Draco18s Thanks for the heads up.  I originally had the MonoBehaviour creating its own GUID, but when I realized that, I put the GUID generation in the custom editor instead.

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it, but unfortunately that returns the same result whether I'm editing the prefab asset from the Project view, or I'm editing the prefab instance within my scene.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, although I don't think it's an ideal one.

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
   var component = this.target as MyScript;

   if (component.gameObject.scene.name.Equals(UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name))
   {
      Debug.Log("editing the prefab instance in the scene");          
   }
   else
   {
      Debug.Log("editing the prefab asset");       
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution that seems to be always working which is

```
if (gameObject.scene.name == null || gameObject.scene.name == gameObject.name)
```

I personally never name a scene the same way I name a prefab so it works well, but I prefer to warn that it will ignore object of the same name than the scene they are in.

Answer (score 0):

I add to prefab empty Game object with name isPrefab and then check its existance

```html
    public bool IsPrefab(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        int childCount = gameObject.transform.childCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        {
            GameObject child = gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
            if (child.name == "isPrefab")
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The function PrefabUtility.IsPartOfPrefabAsset(  ) allow you to know if the given MonoBehavior is part of a Prefab Assets or not !